# Where did the name Smaug come from?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, history-of, names, smaug

So I was wondering what the origin of this name is for the dragon? Is it a known word from a language with a meaning or is it a completely made up word?

Or perhaps it evolved from another word... its a pretty unusual name, and unlikely to originate from an english word (unless it originates from the word smug?)

Did Tolkien ever say where he got the word from ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In his 1938 [letter the the Editor of the Observor](http://www.e-reading.ws/bookreader.php/139008/The_Letters_of_J.R.R.Tolkien.pdf), Tolkien [explicitly stated](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Smaug#Etymology) that the name Smaug is derived from the low Germanic; **"To squeeze through a hole"**.

> "The dragon bears as name – a pseudonym – the past tense of the
>   primitive Germanic verb Smugan, to squeeze through a hole: a low
>   philological jest. The rest of the names are of the Ancient and Elvish
>   World, and have not been modernised."
>   <sub><sup>The Letter of JRR TOlkien - Number 25</sup></sub>

In earlier drafts, Smaug was also know as **Pryftan** (from the Welsh meaning '*Fire Worm*') and **Trāgu**, a corruption of the Old English meaning '*to burrow [into the ground]*'. As @jimmyShelter has noted, the root is identical to [Sméagol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gollum) and [smial](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Smials).

Comment: Interesting fact: this is the same name as Old English Sméagol.

Comment: Jimmy Shelder officially succumbed to the Dark Side of the Stack

Comment: @DVK - Well, it's a new look, certainly.

Comment: Another interesting fact: _pryftan_ (or rather, _pryftân_) does not mean ‘fire worm’ in Welsh—it means ‘worm fire’. It ought to be either _pryf tân_ or _tânpryf_ (or perhaps that should be _tânbryf_; I'm not quite up to scratch on when lenition does and does not occur in Welsh compounds) to mean ‘fire worm’.

Answer (score 0):

I have always thought that the name "Smaug" was related to Polish "smok" = dragon. Tolkien might have had more than one source for this name.

Answer (score -2):

"Smaug" probably came from the name "zmaj" for [Slavic dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_dragon).

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Answer (score -5):

I see the name somehow related to "smog", for the smoke coming from the dragon.

Comment: Not *completely* implausible; the word "smog" goes back at least to 1905.

Comment: But is this just a guess ...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It's really good practice (and matter of politeness) to explain downvotes

Comment: The upvotes on Dave's comment probably indicate why you got downvotes.

Answer (score -5):

There is a type of Lizard Called a [*Smaug giganteus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Girdled_Lizard) or Giant Girdled Lizard, which somewhat looks like a dragon; perhaps he was referring to that.

Comment: The genus was named in reference to the character.