# Meanings of the names in the Hobbit and LOTR?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

I'm a huge hobbit and LOTR fan, so I did some research about the names. I found the meaning of a lot of names but some I didn't find, I thought maybe you can help me?
Here are the names I still don't know:

- Thrór
- Oin
- Gloin
- Dwalin
- Balin
- Bifur
- Bofur
- Bombur
- Fili
- Kili
- Gimli
- Tauriël
- Thranduil
- Smaug
- Azog
- Sauron
- Aragorn
- Gríma
- Elrond
- Galadriel
- Saruman
- Radagast
- Lindir

Comment: You looking for the Earth-meanings (what they mean in real world languages) or what they mean in Tolkien's constructed languages? :)

Comment: I believe that the names of the dwarves may have come from dwarves in Norse mythology. I remember recognizing a few names when I was reading some Norse stuff a while ago. Don't know what they mean, though.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly broad: there's a group of Dwarvish/Mannish names, and one of Elvish. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I'm surprised Ori, Dori, and Nori aren't on the list.

Comment: Sauron and Sauraman are in this Q: Why are the names Sauron and Saruman so similar?

Comment: @MaryML - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85089/why-are-the-names-sauron-and-saruman-so-similar

Comment: @Matt See in the question.. `I found the meaning of a lot of names`

Answer (score 18):

### Dwarves

It's important to remember here that Tolkien's work is, ostensibly, a translation; in-universe, Tolkien has translated ancient manuscripts from "Westron" into English, so the Dwarf-names are not the *actual* Dwarf-names, but rather an approximation of them. However, Tolkien notes:

> I have also translated all Westron names according to their senses.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Appendix F II "On Translation"</sub></sup>

Tolkien frequently notes that he based the "Westron" language on Anglo-Saxon, and later in Appendix F he notes that the Dwarf-names come from a Northern dialect:

> The still more northerly language of Dale is in this book seen only in the names of the Dwarves that came from that region and so used the language of the Men there, taking their 'outer' names in that tongue.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Appendix F II "On Translation"</sub></sup>

This indicates that we can go to Tolkien's out-of-universe source for the Dwarf-names to learn their in-universe meanings. Handy!

In Letter 297, Tolkien reveals this sources: the [*Völuspá*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%B6lusp%C3%A1), a poem from the [*Poetic Edda*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetic_Edda):

> Thus the names of the Dwarves in *The Hobbit* (and additions in the [*Lord of the Rings*]) are derived from the lists in *Völuspá* of the names of *dvergar* [Norse dwarfs]; but this is no key to the dwarf-legends in *The [Lord of the Rings]*.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 297: To 'Mr. Rang' (Draft). August 1967</sub></sup>

You can find the text of the *Völuspá* [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/poe/poe03.htm). Now let's do the names:

- **Thrór** - Probably derived from þrór, which means:

  > Boar.
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>
- **Óin** - Likely derived from Óinn, which means:

  > Shy.
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>
- **Glóin** - Likely derived from Glóinn, which means:

  > The glowing one.
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>
- **Dwalin** - Likely derived from Dvalinn, which means:

  > [Torpid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/torpid).
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>
- **Balin** - This name doesn't appear in the *Eddas*, which makes it somewhat unique among the Dwarf-names. In [*An Introduction to Elvish*](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/An_Introduction_to_Elvish), Tolkien scholar Jim Allan suggests that the name may be related to the Old Norse word "bál", [which means "fire"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%A1l#Old_Norse). "Balin" would presumably then mean something like "Burning one"
- **Bifur** - [Some sources](http://thainsbook.net/dwarves.html#Bifur) claim it's derived from the Old Norse "Bívur", meaning "Trembler." It may also have been from "Bifurr", meaning:

  > Beaver, i.e. one who does things with zeal. *[...]* The name of this animal is often used figuratively for diligence.
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>
- **Bofur** - Possibly from "Bávor", [meaning "Grumbler"](http://thenamegarden.com/post/39657249340/bavor-bavor)
- **Bombur** - Probably from "Bǫmburr", meaning:

  > The swollen one.
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>

  Poor Bombur.
- **Fíli** - This one is unchanged from the *Eddas*; it means:

  > (1) [File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(tool)). (2) By association with weak masculine] nouns formed on tool-names it may mean 'filer,'
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>
- **Kíli** - Also unchanged, this one means:

  > Wedge. Possibly, one who uses a wedge.
  >
  > <sup>"Dwarf-Names: A Study in Old Icelandic Religion" from *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America* Vol. 44 Issue 4</sup>
- **Gimli** - This one is unknown. In Letter 297, Tolkien discusses the Old Norse word *gim*, which he translates as "fire". [Gimlé](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giml%C3%A9) is also a fixture of Norse Mythology: it's where the survivors of Ragnarök will live, and is described in the *Völuspá* as the most beautiful place on Earth

### Elves

In Appendix F, Tolkien notes that he left Elvish names unchanged from the original in his "translation":

> Only the languages alien to the Common Speech have been left in their original form; but these appear mainly in the names of persons and places.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Appendix F II "On Translation"</sub></sup>

So we turn to Tolkien's own (extensive - the man loved his Elvish) writings on Quenya and Sindarin:

- **Tauriel** - An invention of *The Hobbit* movies, Tauriel's name was nonetheless made consistent with the Elvish language. [SFF.SE's own Darth Melkor has previously translated her name](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36619) as "Forest Daughter", though according to Peter Jackson her name means "Daughter of Mirkwood"
- **Thranduil** - I can't find an online copy to verify, but [multiple](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/t/thranduil.html) [sources](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Thranduil#Etymology) indicate that his name is Sindarin for "vigorous spring" according to [*Parma Eldalamberon* 17](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Parma_Eldalamberon_17)
- **Elrond** In Letter 345, Tolkien himself translated it as "vault of stars". In the character index in *The Silmarillion*, it's translated as "star-dome"
- **Galadriel** - In Letter 345, Tolkien translates her name as "Glittering garland". In Letter 348, he gives it again as "Maiden crowned with gleaming hair"
- **Lindir** - From *The Sillmarillion* Appendix: "Elements in Quenya and Sindarin Names" we get *lin-*, meaning "sing". The *-dir* suffix doesn't appear in any writings I can find, but [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Lindir) suggests that it means "man"<sup>1</sup>, in which case "Lindir" would mean "song man" or "singer"

### Wizards

- **Gandalf** - According to *Unfinished Tales*: "The Istari", "Gandalf" translates to "the Elf of the Wand" in the language of the Men of the North

  - Out-of-universe, *Gandálfr* is a Dwarf-name found in *Völuspá*, where it [also means "wand-elf"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gand%C3%A1lfr). Good evidence to support my earlier claim that we can use the out-of-universe meanings to find the in-universe ones!
- **Saruman** - I can't find a direct translation of this. It's possible that it's just a Mannish corruption of his Elvish name, Curunír, which means "man of skill." This is the implication given by "The Istari":

  > The two highest of [the Istari] (of whom it is said there were five) were called by the Eldar Curunír, “the Man of Skill”, and Mithrandir, “the Grey Pilgrim”, but by Men in the North Saruman and Gandalf
  >
  > <sup><sub>*Unfinished Tales* Part 4 Chapter II: "The Istari"</sub></sup>

  [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Saruman#Etymology), citing [*A Reader's Companion*](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings:_A_Reader%27s_Companion), says that it's derived from the Old English [*searu*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/searu), which basically means "work of skill". This suggests that "Saruman", like "Curunír", also translates to "man of skill"
- **Radagast** - Translated in *Unfinished Tales*: "The Istari" as "tender of beasts" in the language of Old Númenor

### Men

- **Aragorn** - In Letter 347, Tolkien suggests that the "Ara-" part is from *aran*, meaning "king". [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Aragorn#Etymology) gives the full translation as "Revered King", but they again cite [*Parma Eldalamberon* 17](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Parma_Eldalamberon_17).

  [In comments, Darth Melkor says](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85479/meanings-of-the-names-in-the-hobbit-and-lotr/85589?noredirect=1#comment188357_85589) that "Aragorn" is translated as "Kingly Valour" in the foreword to *History of Middle-Earth* 12
- **Gríma** - As far as I know, Tolkien never gave a direct meaning for this. It possibly comes from the [Old English word](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/017508), which can mean either "mask" or "spectre".

### Other

- **Smaug** - None given in-universe, but out-of-universe this is given in Letter 25. I'll let Tolkien himself explain this one<sup>2</sup>:

  > The dragon bears as name – a pseudonym – the past tense of the primitive Germanic verb *Smugan*, to squeeze through a hole: a low philological jest.
  >
  > <sup><sub>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 25: To the editor of 'The Observer'. January or February 1938</sub></sup>

  So "Smaug" means "Squeezed through a hole."
- **Azog** - Unfortunately unknown, both in-universe and out. In-universe, we know essentially nothing about the Orcish languages. Out-of-universe, Tolkien never wrote about it. [One theory](http://middle-earth.xenite.org/2012/05/23/where-did-tolkien-get-the-names-azog-and-bolg/) suggests that it's from the Spanish [*azogue*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/azogue), which means "mercury"
- **Sauron** - According to *The Silmarillion* Index of Names, it means "The Abhorred"

---

<sup>1</sup> We can tease this out another way by looking at "Mithrandir", which in the essay "The Istari" is translated from Sindarin as "Grey Pilgrim". According to *The Silmarillion* Appendix: "Elements in Quenya and Sindarin Names", *mith* means "grey" and *rand-* means "wander". "grey wanderer" or "grey wandering man" is a fair approximation of "grey pilgrim", which would suggest that *-dir* means something like "man"

<sup>2</sup> I just now learned that this [was answered before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64298/31051) by SFF.SE's own Richard

Comment: What's quite amusing about all this is that the Dwarf names come out as "Shiny", "Grumbly", "Bashful", "Trembly", "Burny", "Sleepy", etc.

Comment: I suppose we should have guessed the meaning of Bombur's name!

Comment: @DarthMelkor - You missed out Doc. Everyone always does.

Comment: This demonstrates that the names "Smaug" and "Smeagol" are in fact related.

Comment: @MattGutting - and *Smial* (the Hobbit's names for their holes).

Comment: Re: Aragorn, see the Foreword to HoME 12: "his father gave him the name Aragorn, a name used in the House of the Chieftains. But Ivorwen at his naming stood by, and said 'Kingly Valour' (for so that name is interpreted)"; also Letter 347.

Comment: I’m not sure exactly how good Tolkien’s Old Norse was, but I rather thought it would have been better than to make such a non-form as _*Bálinn_ from _bál_. It could of course be straight from _bálin_ ‘the fires’, but there is no verb _*at bála_ to make a participle like _*bálinn_, and even if there were, the verb would mean something more like ‘to make a (bon)fire’, and the participle something like ‘having been made into a bonfire’—which is odd.

Comment: The _Etymologies_ has _*der-_ as the historic root of the word meaning ‘man’. The standard Old Noldorin form is _daer_, but an older form _dîr_ survives in some names in _-dír_ (Haldír, Brandír, Lindír—and we can add Curunír to the list, from _curw_ ‘skill’ + _dîr_) and in the generalised agentive suffix _-dír/-dir_ ‘-er’, which is the one found in _(Mith)randir_: not wandering _man_ as such, just ‘wanderer’. (Quenya has _nér(i)_; the d/n vacillation is in part due to conflation with _nī/nis_ ‘woman’.)

Comment: @MattGutting: Also 'smok' in Polish means 'dragon'

Comment: @MattGutting - on the hobbit side: "små" means "little" or "tiny" in Norwegian.